# How to return truly empty body in rails? i.e. content-length 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to return a 200 status with an empty body but rails returns a body with a single space. i.e. content-length 1

For instance, this code generates a body with the single space

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.html {head :ok}
end
```

and so does this

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.html {render :nothing => true}
end
```

Yes, even render :nothing generates something.

All of this seems to be flowing from a 2005 patch in rails that was designed to fix a bug in Safari where it would ignore the headers if the body was empty. (http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/1818)

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get a 200 status but with a truly empty body? Background: I'm using an API that makes calls to my controllers. I need to send a 200 but the single space body causes the API to malfunction (parse error...). Also, I'll be deploying to Heroku so I can't patch ActionPack to undo the 2005 hack.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This appears to work

```
render :text => ""
```

For Rails 3, you could use:

`render :nothing => true`

In Rails 5, `render :nothing => true` is deprecated (planned for removal in 5.1)

Use

```
def action
  head :ok
end
```

Credit to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34688727/46076) for the Rails 5 solution.

Comment: This works for me too! You're awesome! Thanks for the very quick response. I love how your response is super simple too.

Comment: `render :nothing => true` returns a content-length of 1 with rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Rails 4 answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632271/render-nothing-true-returns-empty-plaintext-file