# "render :nothing => true" returns empty plaintext file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, link-to

I'm on Rails 2.3.3, and I need to make a link that sends a post request.

I have one that looks like this:

```
= link_to('Resend Email', 
  {:controller => 'account', :action => 'resend_confirm_email'}, 
  {:method => :post} )
```

Which makes the appropriate JavaScript behavior on the link:

```
<a href="/account/resend_confirm_email" 
  onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); 
  f.style.display = 'none'; 
  this.parentNode.appendChild(f); 
  f.method = 'POST'; 
  f.action = this.href;
  var s = document.createElement('input'); 
  s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
  s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); 
  s.setAttribute('value', 'EL9GYgLL6kdT/eIAzBritmB2OVZEXGRytPv3lcCdGhs=');
  f.appendChild(s);
  f.submit();
  return false;">Resend Email</a>'
```

My controller action is working, and set to render nothing:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => 200 }
end
```

But when I click the link, my browser downloads an empty text file named "resend_confirm_email."

What gives?

Comment: For rails 5, you can review this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688727/1770571

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is an old answer for legacy Rails versions. For Rails 4+, see William Denniss' post.**

Sounds to me like the content type of the response isn't correct, or isn't correctly interpreted in your browser. Double check your http headers to see what content type the response is.

If it's anything other than `text/html`, you can try to manually set the content type like this:

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'
```

Answer (score 289):

Since Rails 4, `head` is now preferred over `render :nothing`.<sup>[1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)</sup>

```
head :ok, content_type: "text/html"

# or (equivalent)

head 200, content_type: "text/html"
```

is preferred over

```
render nothing: true, status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"

# or (equivalent)

render nothing: true, status: 200, content_type: "text/html"
```

They are technically the same. If you look at the response for either using cURL, you will see:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2014 05:25:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Runtime: 0.014297
Set-Cookie: _blog_session=...snip...; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

However, calling `head` provides a more obvious alternative to calling `render :nothing` because it's now explicit that you're only generating HTTP headers.

---

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses

Comment: Since this also works in Rails 3, it should be the preferred solution for that too (but obviously the OP is on a Rails 2.3 app so the chosen answer was appropriate).

Comment: `head 200` results in a `304` response for me (on rails 4.1.6). The console shows 200 status code, but chrome (network panel) shows 304. The `render :nothing => true` approach worked.

Comment: Is content type necessary if only a header is being returned?