# Internal Server Error 500 gets thrown instead of 404 while trying to access broken picture urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

We have a rails server with custom 404 and 500 pages setup using this tutorial here:

http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages

While it works nice and throws 404s for all kinds of paths, it generates internal server errors 500 while trying to access any kind of suffixed path like en/foo.png, en/foo.pdf, en/foo.xml, ...

But something like en/file.foo throws 404. So only valid suffixes throw a 500.

**End of routes.rb:**

```
if Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
  end

  protected

  def render_404(exception)
    @not_found_path = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def render_500(exception)
    logger.fatal(exception)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/error_500', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 500 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

**500 that appears:**

```
Missing template errors/error_404 with {:locale=>[:de, :en], :formats=>[:png], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :arb, :haml]}
```

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` file and pertinent controller code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We found the mistake.

We had an error_controller.rb containing this:

```
  def error_404
    @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
    render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404
  end
```

and we changed it to fix this problem to:

```
  def error_404
    @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I will add a note at the bottom of the blog post that takes this into account.

Comment: On Rails 4+ `render nothing: true,  status: 404` should be `head :not_found` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/18059789

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`respond_to :html, :json, :png`

and any other necessary formats at the top of your controller. If I'm right, then the problem is that `format.all` in the individual controller actions isn't set up to include `:png` as one of the formats it responds to.

You will probably also need to add to your `config/environment.rb` the following definition and any similar ones:

`Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png`

See more details [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to). Basically you need to set up the mime types that you want to respond to. The error message indicates that rails doesn't understand how to render the format `png`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this wasn't the problem!