# Rails AJAX - don't redirect or render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Using rails and .js.erb to make an AJAX request (and append values to a div), how do you prevent rendering a new layout? In other words, stay on the same page **without going anywhere** and just append the fresh data from the server in a div. No reloading the same page, no redirecting.

At the moment my controller looks like this

```
  def update_shipping
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.shipping_option_id = params[:shipping_options]
    @order.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

and my form like zisss:

```
        <%= form_tag update_shipping_order_path(@order), method: :put, remote: true do %>
          <%= select_tag 'shipping_options', @options_for_select, onchange: 'this.form.submit()' %>
        <% end %>
```

and my routes look like a so:

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    put :update_shipping
  end
end
```

But I get a 'Template is Missing' error

Please help!!

Comment: please post your js code here

Comment: What does your `update_shipping.html.erb` (or .js) look like? The controller wants to render this file by default after your action. Ideally, it should contain only the `div` you want to return to the AJAX function for rendering on your current page.

Comment: $('#shipping_cell').html('<%=j view_in_preferred_currency(@order.shipping_option.price) %>');
@KappaNossi

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `update_shipping.js.erb` file under `app/views/your_controller/` directory. Note the name of the javascript file should be same as the action. Since you have a `remote:true` in your form so rails will try to render a javascript template in your case `update_shipping.js.erb`.

Now in your `update_shipping.js.erb` file write some basic javascript to update the page elements like

```
#update_shipping.js.erb
$('.some-div').html(<%=j @model.some_value' %>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render :nothing => true }
          format.html
        end
```

Comment: I've tried this before.. It causes a blank page to render

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to render a layout, you can use `!request.xhr?` like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { layout: !request.xhr? }
    format.js 
end
```

If you're looking to get your ajax-powered JS to fire, you just need to call your `.js.erb` file the same as your view:

```
#app/views/controller/update_shipping.js.erb
alert("This JS is returned & fired after the Ajax request");
```

You'll be best doing this in your `routes.rb` too:

```
resources :orders do
    put :update_shipping
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, I came across this searching for the same issue. It must of slipped out of my mind at some point while working with action cable, but what is needed is a http response code of no_content. Http response codes tell the browser how to act when a request is returned. [Here is a link to a list of them, and their symbols in rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option). [More on 204 no content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204)

Here is how it would look:

```
def update_shipping
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.shipping_option_id = params[:shipping_options]
    @order.save!

    head :no_content #or head 204
end
```

edit: what solved the solution for me was [a link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses) provided by William Denniss in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632271/render-nothing-true-returns-empty-plaintext-file)