# Rails way of doing error handling to creating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails app. I have a model called `Application`.

In `application_controller.rb`, I have following function

```
def create
        @application = resource.applications.build(attribute: "value")

        if @application.save
           //how should i return response code 200?
        else
            //if @application.save is not run correctly, how do I re-run @application.save?
        end    
end
```

I have total two questions.

1) How do I return response code 200 if @application.save is correctly done?

2) If @application.save is not run correctly for some reason, how do I make sure that @application.save is run again to make sure that the @application is eventually saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From rails 4 you can send head

```
head :ok, content_type: "text/html"
```

For more information you can visit the below link

["render :nothing => true" returns empty plaintext file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632271/render-nothing-true-returns-empty-plaintext-file)

If .save do not save data there will be some reason. Looping until it do not save might not be a good way.

you can check errors by .errors.messages

and if you want still to save skipping model validations then you can use `@application.save(validate: false)`

You cant skip errors from database side I think.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can return response code 200 this way:

   `render status: 200`

   or

   `render status: :ok`
2. It isn't advisable to keep trying to save `@application` since that would be an infinite loop. If it doesn't save for some reason, then that something needs to be addressed with another post request that passes validations; not forcibly run until it will somehow save (which it probably won't anyway).