# The ":nothing" option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This code in rails 5

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def action
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

results in the following deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: :nothing` option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: probably because deprecation warning tells you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @sevenseacat No, it just refers to `head`, that's all. You still have to look up the API being used. Note that this is a Q&A-style post with the goal to quickly solve the above deprecation warning without having to read through the official API. The post is currently raking #1 on google on the above warning, which was my initial goal.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

According to [the rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1099329be081297c16b02141ec13ca6a05ff037c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb#L101), this is done under the hood when passing `nothing: true` in rails 5.

```
if options.delete(:nothing)
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("`:nothing` option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body.")
  options[:body] = nil
end
```

Just replacing `nothing: true` with `body: nil` should therefore solve the problem.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def action
    render body: nil
  end
end
```

[alternatively you can use](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/44781b6e9790d90b4f8b9a41d2b2c114b1a582ee/actionpack/test/controller/action_pack_assertions_test.rb#L6) `head :ok`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def action
    head :ok
  end
end
```

Comment: `render body: nil` worked for me, `render head :ok` didn't (it gave some double render error).

Comment: If you'd like to change the status codes, there are options other than just `:ok` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option

Comment: You can also use `head 403` or any other status code.

Comment: another example would be `head :unauthorized` to return status code 401

Comment: @Dan do you mind explaining why it's the preferred syntax? 
From a code reader standpoint, it makes much more sense for me the `render body: nil` than `head :ok`.

Comment: @Erowlin That's an interesting question. My guess is that I was referencing http://stackoverflow.com/a/18059789/866618, which in turn was referencing the Rails guide. The Rails guide link has changed since when I commented above and the WayBackMachine is offline so I can't tell you what it said back then. The Rails guide link referenced now isn't very definitive...

Comment: @FellowStranger, it's not `render head: :ok`, it's `head :ok`. No `render`. I struggled with that too.

Comment: Confusing. `head` is not a verb unless you "head in a direction"; Adding a new resolving method call to controller actions complexifies behavior; At least using `render status: foo, body: bar` allows a non-Rails dev to have a chance of grokking the code