# The :status option on `head` has been deprecated on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The :status option on `head` has been deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Please pass the status as a separate parameter before the options, instead.
```

It's used in the following context:

```
def options
    head :status => 200, :'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' =>
    'accept, content-type, Authorization, cache-control, x-requested-with'
  end
```

The app uses `devise` for authentication, so I am suspecting this code came along with that. Any suggestion on how to re-write this?

Answer (score 1):

The warning sais 'Please pass the status as a separate parameter before the options, instead.'

which would look like

`head 200`

or more descriptive

`head :ok`

See here for a more detailed answer: [The ":nothing" option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688726/the-nothing-option-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-rails-5-1)